# How to make a synchronous write operation on a Socket with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient, zebra-printers

I am trying to send a huge amount of data to a Zebra printer (ZE500), a bunch of PNGs for instance. Sending 2 MB of bitmaps to this printer and storing them into its internal flash is a very slow process, so I need to know when this task terminates.
This is a piece of code that I would use to make a synchronous write through a tcp socket connected to the printer.

```
public void Write(string ip, int port, byte[] data)
{
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port))
    {
        using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: why does the `stream.Write` call ends instantly, even if the socket is still sending data to the printer and the property `Socket.Blocking` is set to true?

That write operation is not already finished, but the call ends like it was completed.
What am I missing here?

Comment: The operating system/driver is probably buffering the data. Why do you care why does it need to be synchronous? And why can't you use `await stream.WriteAsync`

Comment: @Charlieface because, for example, if I close the program before all the data is completely sent, the socket will be disposed and that would result in a connection reset --> transfer aborted. I can't use awaits because I am writing a software with the 3.5 .NET Framework and I can't upgrade it.

Comment: Are you sure that's actually what happens? I would imagine that disposal of `NetworkStream` (via the `using`) would automatically flush the socket.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong with the connection reset, but I still don't know if the write was successfully completed while I am running the program. I need to know it because I am writing a software that throws as Event when all the images into the printer are successfully stored. I could ask the printer status after trasferring the images to get a response at the end of the transfer (that would be a successfull result), but it can last even 5 minutes and during that timespan the printer is not able to return any response. In these conditions I am completely blind about what is going on.

Comment: Have you run a Wireshark trace? It is possible that the printer's network card has already received it, but the printer is taking time to process the data

Comment: I did some tests with Wireshark, and no, the printer receives and process the data on the fly, it doesn't wait to receive the whole stream, since the data is made of multiple separated commands.